# How can I solve Trying to get property of non-object?

Tags: php, json

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
if (isset($data)) {
    $request = json_decode($data);
    $un = $request->username;
    $mob = $request->mobile;
    $em = $request->email;
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and show some of the JSON returned. You can use ```echo print_r($request,true)``` to see what the decoded JSON looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this error is happening is because the HTTP request *does not* contain a JSON object with with your expected properties. For example, if you are getting the error when grabbing the username, it means that your JSON object does not have a `username` property.